# iOS crashing, unknown cause

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on an iOS framework and an app is crashing with it. Not sure where the problem lies. Based on the log, Im thinking that an object is being released manually, but then is autoreleased, again causing the crash. Has anyone seen a crash like this before? Not sure if this is caused by my framework or the app using it.

```
Crashed: com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0xfffffffff objc_object::release() + 8
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0xfffffffff (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 724
2  CoreFoundation                 0xfffffffff _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 28
3  libdispatch.dylib              0xfffffffff _dispatch_client_callout2 + 12
4  libdispatch.dylib              0xfffffffff _dispatch_apply_invoke_and_wait + 165
5  libdispatch.dylib              0xfffffffff dispatch_apply_f + 650
6  CoreFoundation                 0xfffffffff -[__NSSetM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 295
7  MyFramework                    0xfffffffff MyFunction + 18550
8  MyFramework                    0xfffffffff MyFunction + 18450
9  libdispatch.dylib              0xfffffffff _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
10 libdispatch.dylib              0xfffffffff _dispatch_client_callout + 16
11 libdispatch.dylib              0xfffffffff _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 928
12 libdispatch.dylib              0xfffffffff _dispatch_queue_invoke + 884
13 libdispatch.dylib              0xfffffffff _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 344
14 libdispatch.dylib              0xfffffffff _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 540
15 libdispatch.dylib              0xfffffffff _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 124
16 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xfffffffff _pthread_wqthread + 1096
17 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xfffffffff start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: Have you tried setting an Exception breakpoint or used a Memory Instrument? Because there isn't enough here to go on.

Comment: Yes, problem is I can't reproduce the crash. And the function listed in the log from my framework is very simple, which leads me to believe it isnt my framework that is causing the crash. I was hoping someone would be familiar with the objc_object::release() and (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) calls.

Comment: Maybe you try to reproduce the crash and get the sequence to make it crash then only you can debug it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see a crash with `_dispatch_root_queue_drain` in the stack trace it means some block has already executed on that queue and the autorelease pool is being drained

you need to check any memory leak for the object that is being released such crash happen when a block is executed on thread but is being called again with a new object release so try checking following link it may help Probably its due to memory issue and object re release

```
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/EradicatingZombies.html
```